# How to execute perl script from java in ubuntu

Tags: java, perl, ubuntu

I have a perl script that needs 2 arguments to be run. I am currently using Ubuntu and I managed to execute the perl script from terminal by changing directory to where the perl script exists and by writing

```
perl tool.pl config=../mydefault.config file=../Test
```

However, when I am trying to run the perl script from my java program (I am using eclipse), It always gives me the message `Command Failure`. This is the code :

```
Process process;
try {
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl /home/Leen/Desktop/Tools/bin/tool.pl config=../mydefault.config file=../Test");
    process.waitFor();
    if(process.exitValue() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Command Successful");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Command Failure");
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception: "+ e.toString());
}
```

So please what is wrong in my code?

Comment: have you checked the exist status of the command when run from the terminal? `$?`.  Are you sure you're running it from the right directory in the Java code?

Comment: The path inside exec. function seems wrong. Printout System.properties and check the runtime environment before run the script. Or try with absolute path: I mean /home/user/....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be [separating the command from it's arguments in the call to `exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29), such as:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"perl", "/home/Leen...", "config=...", "file=..."});
```

With what you currently have, Runtime is looked for a command *literally named* `perl /home/Leen/Desktop...`, spaces and all.

When you run the whole command from the Terminal, your shell is smart enough to realize that a space delimits the name of the command (`perl`) from the arguments that should be passed to it (`/home/Leen/Desktop...`, `config=...`, `file=...`). Runtime.exec() is not that smart.